# How to set copters Attitude via DroneKit -- SET_ATTITUDE_TARGET not working

Tags: dronekit-python

I have Dronekit working properly with SITL sim, however for my project I want to be able to command the attitude of the copter. Obviously I can do this via RC over ride in ALT_HOLD mode, however I don't like that approach.

I have been trying to use the Mavlink message SET_ATTITUDE_TARGET (#82), however when I send the messages to the sim, nothing happens. I have been able to set the velocity and the position, and those work fine.

Here is my function:

```
def att_msg_mode():
    print "=========== Building Message"
    veh1.mode = VehicleMode("ALT_HOLD")
    msg = veh1.message_factory.set_attitude_target_encode(
    0,
    0,                #target system
    0,                #target component
    0b11100010,       #type mask
    [.9438,0,0,.17364], #q
    0,                #body roll rate
    0,                #body pitch rate
    0,                #body yaw rate
    0)                #thrust
    time.sleep(1)
    veh1.send_mavlink(msg)
    veh1.flush()
    print "=========== Message Sent"
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not possible to set the attitude directly because the command is not supported by Copter in either guided mode or AUTO mode/missions). The list of [supported commands in guided mode is here](http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/copter-commands-in-guided-mode/) and [AUTO commands here](http://copter.ardupilot.com/wiki/common-planning-a-mission-with-waypoints-and-events/common-mavlink-mission-command-messages-mav_cmd/).

What you can do is [set the yaw](http://python.dronekit.io/guide/copter/guided_mode.html). Another (hacky) approach that may work is [setting the ROI](http://python.dronekit.io/guide/copter/guided_mode.html#setting-the-roi) as this will point the camera (and often the whole vehicle) at a target.

This sounds like a reasonable requirement - perhaps [create a request](https://github.com/diydrones/dronekit-python/issues) with explanation of why this is useful for you?

Answer (score 4):

[SET_ATTITUDE_TARGET](http://mavlink.org/messages/common#SET_ATTITUDE_TARGET) is now available to be used in [guided_mode](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot/pull/2959).
You can even test it using [mavproxy](https://ardupilot.github.io/MAVProxy/html/modules/cmdlong.html) attitude command.

Answer (score 0):

`SET_ATTITUDE_TARGET` is now implemented, and will be released with ArduCopter 3.4