# How to set GUIDED_NOGPS mode with Arducopter on Dronekit?

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

How do I command Arducopter to enter guided_nogps mode?  I am planning to operate in a gps denied environment, and although other posts indicate this is possible with guided-nogps, I cannot see how to set that mode. Using Dronekit (python) vehicle.mode = VehicleMode("Guided_NoGPS") returns an error indicating there is no such mode.

Mavlink also refuses to acknowledge the mode.

My setup is a Pixhawk running Arducopter with a Raspberry Pi companion.  Firmware is v3.5 dev, and v3.4 on the DroneKit-SITL (I compiled my own v3.4 binary for this).

Everything else is working great (e.g. controlling via set_attitude_target thanks to this post [How to set copters Attitude via DroneKit -- SET_ATTITUDE_TARGET not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391721/how-to-set-copters-attitude-via-dronekit-set-attitude-target-not-working/31394868#31394868) ) - I just need to be able to go indoors!

Also - I did notice in this post prior to the release of Arducopter v3.4 [Controlling movement without GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123827/controlling-movement-without-gps/33354803#33354803) that an optical flow sensor might be required.  Did that requirement come to pass?

Thanks again!

All advice welcome.

Thanks Squilter for your help.  I created a function to change the flightmode (20):

```
def set_mode(flightmode):
# create the MAV_CMD_DO_SET_MODE command
msg = vehicle.message_factory.command_long_encode(
    0, 0,    # target system, target component
    mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_DO_SET_MODE, #command
    0, #confirmation
    flightmode,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 )
# send command to vehicle
vehicle.send_mavlink(msg)
```

The message is correctly received but was not successful (result 3 returned).  One thing I wasn't sure about was parameter 2, which the spec indicates is platform specific.  I put 0 as I wasn't sure what to do with it for Arducopter.

Again, any suggestions welcome and many thanks!

Comment: This is an unfortunate inconsistency with mavlink devices. Some devices change their mode with a `MAV_CMD_DO_SET_MODE` packed into a `command_long` . For ArduCopter, however, you must send a `SET_MODE` message.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the mode to 20. This is the internal representation of the mode. It looks like dronekit-python does not know this yet.

Optical flow is required for normal guided mode, not guided_nogps. However, guided_nogps does not allow sending velocity or position requests, only angles.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I have tried setting the mode to 20.  The console is giving the correct command_ack code, but the result is 3, which I believe means it was not successful. Here is my function:

Comment: I'll add my function above.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is a little old but I have found the answer. Update your installs of MAVProxy and PyMAVLink.

```
pip install -U pymavlink mavproxy
```

DroneKit will automatically install older versions of them without the new modes available. You want **PyMAVLink >= 2.2.4** and **MAVProxy >= 1.6.1.**